# Will it be possible to activate Windows XP (SP3) after April 8, 2014?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-activation

I get that [Windows XP SP3 (...) Support Ends April 8, 2014](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/endofsupport.aspx) and I get that this means: (from the site linked to above)

> - there will be no new security updates
> - [no] non-security hotfixes
> - [no] free or paid assisted support options
> - [no] online technical content updates

All fine and well, but what about activation? Will I be able to (re-)activate my legacy Windows XP systems - maybe (or *especially*) running in a VM -- after this date? (Obviously license permitting, that is, non-OEM licenses.)

Has this question been addressed by Microsoft?

Comment: They are ending support not activation, I suppose MS could disable activation for XP at any time after 2014 date, know way to know the future as there are no statements by Microsoft about this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A user on [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-windows_install/future-windows-xp-activation-support/8b64edf7-8146-e011-9bac-78e7d160ad4e?msgId=bae49a41-9b46-e011-90b6-1cc1de79d2e2) (thanks @Martin) says:

> "Microsoft will also support the activation of Windows XP throughout its life and will likely provide an update that turns activation off at the end of the product's lifecycle so users would no longer be required to activate the product."

Please note that others also asked the same question: [Will I be able to activate XP after 2014?](http://www.pcworld.com/article/250774/will_i_be_able_to_activate_xp_after_2014.html)

I haven't found any official documentation to back up any claims though. But a user on the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1760154.html) has an interesting point:

> If it's officially discontinued it would mean no support, so would you want to run it?

Comment: Thanks. That quote is rather nice. It's also on this MS answers site: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-windows_install/future-windows-xp-activation-support/8b64edf7-8146-e011-9bac-78e7d160ad4e?msgId=bae49a41-9b46-e011-90b6-1cc1de79d2e2

Comment: @Martin I'm still looking for that FAQ that he mentions :(

Comment: well, at least on the MS site the answers were given by people with the MVP badge. Not foolproof by far, but IMHO better than the SpiceWorks forum :-)

Comment: @Martin You're right. I took the liberty to include your link in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Microsoft since this question was asked already indicate activations will still be possible at least until Windows 7 is supported ( because of Windows XP Mode ).  I don't have a link.  Somebody else can find it if they are interested.

Comment: I activated a XP running under Virtualbox last week via the automated phone support. I was unable to use the server. I use XP to run an old program originally for Win 95 and do not use network/internet. So I should be safe.