# WinXP asks for registration after fixing MBR

Tags: windows-xp, boot, grub, mbr

I have a WinXP development disk which was originally installed via MSDN CDs and DDK, and recently tried booting it after several years of non-use.

When I encountered a GRUB error for non-existant drive/partition, I realized it was likely used in a dual-drive configuration. So I used the method of repairing the MBR from an Ubuntu 16.04 live CD session via the syslinux mbr.bin package.

This worked great for rebooting the XP drive until I tried logging in, which asked to validate the copy of XP on Microsoft server, then failed.

I still have the MSDN WinXP CDs and CD keys, and even tried repairing the MBR via 'fixmbr' command in XP live CD repair session, but rebooting into WinXP still blocks me on the validation step.

This would have been validated a long time ago at the time of active XP development, so I'm worried that the syslinux MBR repair step might have reset the validation info.

Since XP is no longer even supported by MicroSoft, does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

--DaveM

Comment: If you are using a different motherboard, NIC and/or HDD configuration then that'll trigger XP needing to be (re)activated.  What did MS say when you called their phone activation system?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will it be possible to activate Windows XP (SP3) after April 8, 2014?](http://superuser.com/questions/407739/will-it-be-possible-to-activate-windows-xp-sp3-after-april-8-2014)

Comment: Activate the installation by phone.

Comment: OK, so the most likely explanation for this showing up on the XP drive now is that the motherboard / system is not the same as when it last worked.

Comment: After googling for tips on Windows XP activation, modifying the registry key for WPAEvents now pops up a dialog "Windows is already activated" after logging in, then logs off.